# Nested/ child Component is not part of any NgModule

Tags: typescript, angular6

I am working on Angular 6 application. I have have parent component 'Consultation' which is referenced in consultation.module in provider and then I have nested component insider Consultation component and test component whose references are also in consultation.module in provider, followed by consultation.module reference added in app.module. structure as following;

I am getting error SurveyComponent is not part of any NgModule even due is been referred in component.module, not sure what I am missing here???

### error

```
Error: Component SurveyComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
```

[image]

### ConsultationModule

```
@NgModule({
imports:[
    CommonModule
],
declarations: [ 
    ConsultationComponent,
    SurveyComponent,
    TestingComponent
 ]
})

export class ConsultationModule{
}
```

### App.Module // root level

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
  ConsultationModule
],
export class AppModule { }
```

### app.routing

```
export const routes: Routes = [

{
path: 'consultation',
component: ConsultationComponent,
data: {
  title: 'Consultation' 
}     
},
 {
 path: 'survey',
 component: SurveyComponent,
 data: {
   title: 'Survey' 
 }     
 }
];
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to put your routing config for your consultation module inside of the consultation module and then import those routes.

Comment: i tried but throw routing error, but at the movement I am trying to solve ngModule error

Comment: well i believe your problem is actually with your routing set up. Your declaring routes in your main module with components declared in child modules, and those components are not exported.  Exporting them from the consultation module may work. but the better path is to put routing configs within the modules they belong to.

Answer (score 0):

the problem you are facing is in here

```
 {
    path: 'survey',
    component: SurveyComponent,
    data: {
    title: 'Survey' 
 }
```

as you cannot set a path to a component which is nested into another module you need to push that component to the declarations array in app module or you set it into Consultation Module Routing file and would be better to make it lazy loaded